# Return the label of a slider instead of the value in the callback

Tags: python, slider, plotly-dash

I have this code:

```
    from dash import Dash, html, dcc
    from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
    
    app = Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Slider(0, 10,
    step=None,
    marks={
        0: '0 kid',
        3: '3 kids',
        5: '5 kids',
        10: '10 kids'
    },
    value=5,
    id="my-slider"
), html.Div(id='slider-output-container')])

@app.callback(
    Output('slider-output-container', 'children'),
    Input('my-slider', 'value'))
def update_output(value):
    #return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

We can use this syntax if we use value without a label.
How can i get "You have selected 5 kids" instead of "You have selected 5"

[image]

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to solve this problem. First, try to define a dictionary and add it to marks inside `dcc.Slider` and then reuse it inside the callback.

Full example:

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = Dash()

marks_dict={           #<------ this is the new dictionary
        0: '0 kid',
        3: '3 kids',
        5: '5 kids',
        10: '10 kids'
    }

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Slider(0, 10,
    step=None,
    marks=marks_dict,
    value=5,
    id="my-slider"
), html.Div(id='slider-output-container')])

@app.callback(
    Output('slider-output-container', 'children'),
    Input('my-slider', 'value'))
def update_output(value):
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(marks_dict[value])
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

[image]

[image]